# Marking the clicked button as active

Tags: html, css, wordpress, button

Given this HTML:

```
<div class="wp-editor-tabs"><button type="button" id="bbp_topic_content-tmce" class="wp-switch-editor switch-tmce" data-wp-editor-id="bbp_topic_content">Visual</button>
<button type="button" id="bbp_topic_content-html" class="wp-switch-editor switch-html" data-wp-editor-id="bbp_topic_content">Text</button>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdruawqc/)

They look like:

[image: Buttons]

Is it possible so that when one button is clicked it kind of becomes activated and thus has a thicker border or some other indicator. And then, if you click the other button, that one shows as active and the other reverts back to normal styling?

In addition, when the page is first displayed it would know which to show as active. In context these buttons are related to a bbPress support forum and toggling between two editors.

Can what I want to do be achieved with CSS?

Comment: Guessing you've got your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only CSS

```css
.wp-switch-editor:focus-within {
    border: thin solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wp-editor-tabs"><button type="button" id="bbp_topic_content-tmce" class="wp-switch-editor switch-tmce" data-wp-editor-id="bbp_topic_content">Visual</button>
<button type="button" id="bbp_topic_content-html" class="wp-switch-editor switch-html" data-wp-editor-id="bbp_topic_content">Text</button>
</div>
```

With jQuery

```js
$('.wp-switch-editor').on('click', function(){
  $('.wp-switch-editor').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  border: 1px solid #000;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wp-editor-tabs"><button type="button" id="bbp_topic_content-tmce" class="wp-switch-editor switch-tmce" data-wp-editor-id="bbp_topic_content">Visual</button>
<button type="button" id="bbp_topic_content-html" class="wp-switch-editor switch-html" data-wp-editor-id="bbp_topic_content">Text</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume the jQuery approach would require changes to my php template files? Or can this kind of thing be done with a php snippet (using WordPress snippet plugin)?

Comment: It would require that you either use a plugin where you can write javascript in, or that you enqueue your own. -

Answer (score 1):

You can use :focus, but it may not behave how you want in practice. I would recommend using javascript/jQuery instead.

```css
.wp-editor-tabs button:focus {
  border:3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wp-editor-tabs">
  <button type="button" id="bbp_topic_content-tmce" class="wp-switch-editor switch-tmce" data-wp-editor-id="bbp_topic_content">Visual</button>
  <button type="button" id="bbp_topic_content-html" class="wp-switch-editor switch-html" data-wp-editor-id="bbp_topic_content">Text</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
 <div class="wp-editor-tabs"><button type="button" id="bbp_topic_content-tmce" class="btn wp-switch-editor switch-tmce" data-wp-editor-id="bbp_topic_content">Visual</button>
    <button type="button" id="bbp_topic_content-html" class="btn wp-switch-editor switch-html" data-wp-editor-id="bbp_topic_content">Text</button>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
button {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Style the active class, and buttons on mouse-over */
.active, .btn:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

JS

```
// Get the container element
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myDIV");

// Get all buttons with class="btn" inside the container
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");

// Loop through the buttons and add the active class to the current/clicked button
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Jquery:

```
<style>
  .button{
    border:1px solid blue;
    height: 50px;   
    margin:10px;
  }
</style>

<button id="button1" class="button">Visual</button>
<button id="button2" class="button">Text</button>

<script>
   $('.button').click(function(){
       $(this).parent().find('.button').css('background-color','#ffffff');
       $(this).css('background-color','#ff0000');
   });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jeagerck/1v7h3szc/5/

Answer (score 1):

```
var button = document.querySelectorAll("#bbp_topic_content-tmce")[0];
button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var $classList = event.currentTarget.classList;
  if(!$classList.contains("clicked")) {
    $classList.add("clicked");
  } else {
    $classList.remove("clicked");
  }

});
```

```js
var button = document.querySelectorAll("#bbp_topic_content-tmce")[0];
button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
 var $classList = event.currentTarget.classList;
  if(!$classList.contains("clicked")) {
   $classList.add("clicked");
  } else {
   $classList.remove("clicked");
  }
 
});
```

```css
.clicked {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wp-editor-tabs"><button type="button" id="bbp_topic_content-tmce" class="wp-switch-editor switch-tmce" data-wp-editor-id="bbp_topic_content">Visual</button>
<button type="button" id="bbp_topic_content-html" class="wp-switch-editor switch-html" data-wp-editor-id="bbp_topic_content">Text</button>
</div>
```

Comment: not to spoil anything, but it doesn't work when you click `text`

Comment: I have added to Visual Button only